# Unable to find directory of the external hard disk (Linux)

Tags: hard-drive

this is the first time I've experienced this problem: I have external hard disk connected to my Linux PC. It always worked and I could always access it through VPN as well. However, now when I want to go to the harddisk subdirectory in my "Media" directory (using VPN from home), there is no hard disk directory as it used to be. I assume it could be somehow related to the powercut (which occurred in whole building). Electricity is now on, my office PC is turned on, everything else works...except my external hard disk can't be found even though it is connected to to my PC and turned on as well. I would like to know if this happens normally? And is there any trick how to fix it?

Thank You.

Comment: You've provided no specifics as to what OS/product/release you're using.  Is this a Ubuntu Core server? Ubuntu Server? Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu *flavor* etc.. what release of *unstated* product?  What actual error message(s) do you get when you attempt to `mount` (via command or GUI tool - which tool did you try).  Does the drive exist in your *file-system table*? or how was it mounted... You've currently provided few specifics.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find the external hard drive in the Disks application to mount it then it's game over for the external hard drive because of the power cut. To prevent this unfortunate situation from happening again get an external SSD to replace the external HDD next time. SSDs have no moving parts, and force shutting down the computer when they are mounted doesn't seem to damage them.